# What are do these changes in my org mean ?

Tags: setup, trailhead

I am seeing the same change in many of my orgs in the

> Setup Audit Trail

. We have not done any code change. Are others seeing this too? What change does this imply ?

> Automated Process Created custom field: OrigGoalId (Text)
>   Automated Process Created custom field: OrigMetricId (Text)

Answer (score 0):

Changes made to your org by way of a script may be logged as Automated Process or salesforce.com (and possibly other faux users, but I've only seen these two in the wild). Some changes to an org create audit trails, but run under a different security context than the user that requested the change.

For example, enabling a feature in setup might invoke a script that changes the org in the "salesforce.com" context. Technical support and other authorized users can make changes in Black Tab (the backend administration system) that can leave audit logs. Internal salesforce.com developers can run scripts against orgs that will leave audit trails. And, of course, joining a pilot program can cause metadata changes as well.

The audit system is an accountability feature, and reflects not just changes made by local system administrators, but unusual (i.e. not global, like a release) changes made by salesforce.com on behalf of a client.

I'm not aware of what these changes represent, nor do I have an exhaustive list of the various features that may cause audit logs. However, I can say that these changes are definitely benign, and are no cause for concern. I couldn't find any documentation on these fields, so if you're truly curious, contact technical support.